# understanding dependency injection in PHP

Tags: php, oop

```
class Author {
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->lastName;
    }
}

class Question {
    private $author;
    private $question;

    public function __construct($question, Author $author) {
        $this->author = $author;
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getAuthor() {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getQuestion() {
        return $this->question;
    }
}
```

Class author is injected into the constructor of Question class am I correct? but how to call the Question class to get the author's name?

```
$question = new Question('What is PHP', 'Adam');
$question->getFirstname;
```

like this? I assume Question class inherited Author class so Question's instance can use the function of Author Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

```
echo $question->getAuthor()->getFirstName();
```

Think of it this way if it helps

```
$author = $question->getAuthor();
echo $author->getFirstName();
```

Also note that you can't construct a `Question` with the string "Adam", you need to pass an instance of `Author`

```
$question = new Question('What is PHP', new Author('Adam', 'Lastname'));
```

Comment: so the final would be like this?

 $question = new Question('What is PHP', new Author('Adam', 'Lastname'));
echo $question->getAuthor()->getFirstName();

Comment: @jameslebron yes. You could also construct author beforehand, eg `$author = new Author('Foo', 'Bar'); $q = new Question('Eh?', $author);`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new method:

```
class Question 
{
    // ...
    function getAuthorFirstname()
    {
        return $this->author->getFirstname();
    }
}

$question = new Question(.., new Author(..., ...));
echo $question->getAuthorFirstname();
```

Or, if you don't really care about [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) or feel that it doesn't apply:

```
$question = new Question(.., new Author(..., ...));
echo $question->getAuthor()->getFirstname();
```

In the end it all comes down to striking a balance between information hiding and pragmatism.

Comment: ah this is method chaining right? so my code of calling the getFirstname is wrong? what if I wish not to to change anything in my Question class?

Comment: @jameslebron I've added a second part to my answer; also read up on "Law of Demeter".

Comment: Is that really violating LoD? `getAuthor()` returns the `Author` instance so at that point, we're out of `Question`

Comment: @Phil Well, the term "units 'closely' related to the current unit" is up for interpretation I suppose.

Comment: In fact, using your `getAuthorFirstName` example implies that `Question` has *knowledge* of `Author`

Comment: `getAuthor()` simply returns a value of type `Author`. I don't see the LoD specifying that only primitive types may be returned. It doesn't make a lot of sense to "unwrap" all complex types and provide direct access methods to their primitive values, that just increases complexity and dependencies.

Comment: @Phil It owns Author so naturally it should also know about what it can do.

Comment: Jeeze, harsh critics around here. Have an upvote for at least thinking about design principals (and making me read articles I haven't read in ages)

Comment: Qualifier: it *does* make sense to implement something like `getAuthorFirstname()` if you want to hide the internal implementation completely and not propagate knowledge of an `Author` object beyond this class. However, if the consumer of a `Question` object is expected to have knowledge of the `Author` type, it doesn't make sense to hide it at the cost of increased complexity.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I've refined my statement about whether or not to use the second option :) if, after reading LoD it can be argued that it's not a problem, obviously that's the simpler way.

Comment: Meh, okay, I'm slightly appeased. :o)

Comment: @deceze Arguments over design principles are always a delicate matter and hardly ever absolute, which is exactly why I try to avoid them :)

Comment: Very true. At least you need to evenly balance all possible viewpoints... Which can be quite trying.